# rxjs 5 for map , catch , throw convert to 6.5 syntax to get response json from backend

Tags: angular, rxjs

hey I am very next I angular, I work with a team where they use very old angular, and I am trying to upgrade a lot of things, my previous **rxjs** is in version 5.4, 
and now I upgrade it to be 6.5 
map and catch and throw not accept any more, and I have read some articles also how to convert them, but still unclear because most articles do not explain how to get a response it by json()

here is my previous rxjs 5.4 syntax

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import "rxjs/add/operator/catch";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import "rxjs/add/observable/throw";

createDataParam(url, data, params) {
    return this.http
      .post(url, data, { params: params })
      .map(response => response.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

and how to convert it to be **rsjx** newest version syntax ??

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators"
```

i tried to `.pipe(map(res => res.json()) )` it doesnt working, and the catch also

```
params mean is for token
```

i do love to get the very simple example from you all, so i will try to understand it, I create that for reusable method, so I can use to any component

thank you that already read this, hope I can get some suggestion and help here :)

Answer (score 1):

When you use the new rxjs operators with the pipe command you have to remember they return an observable so you won't be able to return a json object with map.  What map returns is an observable of the json object in your example.  You would then need to subscribe to it to get the data out as a json object.

As for catch the operator is now catchError if you want to use it inside the pipe.

```
createDataParam(url, data, params) {
    return this.http
      .post(url, data, { params: params })
      .pipe(
          map(response => response.json()),
          catchError(this.handleError),
       )
       .subscribe(result => result) 
  }
```

Comment: should i import also the catchError like I did on the map?

Comment: @ZumDummi yes import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) , you can simple subscribe the observable. Convert to json will automatically take care of by angular itself

```
createDataParam(url, data, params) {
    return this.http
      .post(url, data, { params: params })
      .pipe(              
          catchError(this.handleError),
       )
       .subscribe(result => result) 
  }
```

Comment: is that mean that we don't need use map ?? and we should import thr catctError? right??